# Use docker-compose to pull images from private repository

Tags: docker, docker-compose, microservices

I'm using docker-compose command to run multiple containers. The problem is my docker-compose has to pull some images from the public repository and some from a private repository. What I'm planning to do is push all required images to the private repository but how can I make docker-compose pull the images from the private repository.

In short -> How to point to a private repository when the images are only available there

Comment: What registry are you using?

Comment: we are using jfrog

Comment: Accessing a private image should be the same as a public one, except for the authentication part. For example, your Dockerfile base image should still be something like this: `FROM private/repo:tag`, and should be the same in Docker Compose. Docker Hub and Amazon ECR can be accessed by using their CLI to authenticate, in your case, I can only point you to JFrog's registry page: [click here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Docker+Registry)

Comment: We have an assumption that the end-user does not have the docker file. He only has a docker compose file which should automatically pull images he has mentioned in the `docker-compose.yml` file when when he does `docker-compose up`

Comment: Yes, so it should work the same way. I believe that JFrog gives you a custom URI for your private repository, but in order to gain access to that repository URI, you must authenticate or log-in.

Comment: Thanks @serey...login worked

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use `docker login` command. ([Official doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/))
Enter your credentials, and then you can pull private image, only if you have an access.

> If you want to login to a self-hosted registry you can specify this by adding the server name.

```
docker login localhost:8080
```

Thanks to [@herm's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7683711/herm) comment, if you want to use swarm, use : 
`--with-registry-auth` option.
Personnaly, I use this command :

```
docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth --compose-file dev.compose.yml myProjectName
```

Comment: Fyi: when using docker stack deploy in a swarm the --with-registry-auth option will forward the login information to other nodes.

Comment: If you host the image on a private Artifactory Enterprise server instance, you can't just do `docker login` `docker pull imageName`.  You have to do `docker login artifactory.myCompany.com` `docker pull artifactory.myCompany.com/imageName:label`.  However, even after logging in on the command line, and then running my docker-compose file which contains `image: artifactory.myCompany.com/imageName:label`, I still get the error `pull access denied for imageName, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'`

Comment: I seemed to need to add an extra pull command e.g. `docker login <host> && docker compose pull && docker compose up` or I'd get `failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to authorize: failed to fetch anonymous token: unexpected status: 401 Unauthorized`