# Why can't pull images from ecr on aws automatically in a docker swarm cluster?

Tags: image, amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

Use this way to deploy an application which has been built as a docker image hosted on ecr:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: [AWS_ECR_REPO_URL]/app0:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

Deploy it:

```
$ docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml app0
```

Then use `docker images` to check the images local, can't find the `[AWS_ECR_REPO_URL]/app0:latest` at all.

If pull the repo myself, it can be get:

```
$ docker pull [AWS_ECR_REPO_URL]/app0:latest
```

I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Enter your credentials using `docker login` if you want to pull the private image.
- Specify server name want to login into self-hosted registry

  docker login server-name (localhost)
- Use `--with-registry-auth` option for swarm

  docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth

Comment: I have did that. As I said I can pull the image using this way: `docker pull [AWS_IMAGE]`. But can't pull automatically by run `docker stack deploy ...`.

Comment: Have you check --with-registry-auth with swarm (stack deploy)? Ref. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45567201/user-docker-compose-to-pull-images-from-private-repository?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: That's the key point. It works when I added `--with-registry-auth`! Thanks!