# Dockerfile private parent image specification in FROM

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-registry

Is there a way to specify a private docker image? I can't seem to find any reference for it.

Dockerfile looking something like:

`FROM myprivate_registry/myprivate_image`

If not, is the only way to do this by caching the parent image locally first, and then referring to it in the `FROM` statement?

Update: my question is about specifying a private image in the Dockerfile, not pulling from a private registry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User docker-compose to pull images from private repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45567201/user-docker-compose-to-pull-images-from-private-repository)

Comment: Yes that is possible, have you tried it?

Comment: tried it, doesnt work with private images. building the dockerfile just says it cannot find the image, and to make sure Im logged in (which I am). The only way this works is if I refer to a public image in FROM

Comment: @sargeMonkey are you using BuildKit? What version of docker?

Comment: Docker Desktop on windows, Version 2.0.0.3 (31259). I'm not familiar with BuildKit